# Pure CSS grid sixths

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

Using [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/) from Yahoo.

With the below code block, the first two div grids render as expected. Children of the first div are all 1/6th and the children of second are 1/6th and 5/6th. However, with the third one, the 1/6th renders fine but the other two, 3/6th and 2/6th get messed up as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u8ywdx06/1/). Anyone know why?

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 1 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 2 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 3 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 4 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 5 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 6 </div>
</div>
<div id="content" role="main" class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 1 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-5-6"> 2 </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-6"> 1 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-3-6"> 2 </div>
    <div class="pure-u-2-6"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no classes `pure-u-3-6` and `pure-u-2-6` in pure.css

Use `pure-u-1-2` and `pure-u-1-3` instead.

Your updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u8ywdx06/2/

Comment: Thanks. I get the grid system in Pure now. I was under the impression that it somehow automatically scales it to any fraction you give it. I wish it were a bit more 'semantic' though.

Comment: @JeevanJose It's a smaller and more efficient file that way. I think all of the 24ths are present though, so you don't always need to reduce your fractions. It's probably a good practice to get in the habit of though.